# increment a value every day in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, increment

I want to increment a value in MySQL everyday. Starting with 0 and adding +1 for each day.

I've looked at several methods but it usually involves parsing it out of the calendar and starts getting messy. Does anyone have a nice solution for how I could do this in php/mysql?

Reason:
I have a table of data and want to email 1 row each day. So row 0 will send on day one, then row 2 on day 2.

Comment: Is this running on a background process? How is this being triggered?

Comment: How you are sending mail? Are you using cron?

Comment: If you have a cron job that runs once a day, then you can have additional boolean `is_sent` field in your table, so your script will retrieve the first (in whatever sense you program it) `not sent` row, email the data, and mark the row as `sent`.

Comment: Store 0 "somewhere", increment the value every time your job runs. But this really sounds like a hack. Aren't you trying to send the last (most recent) row from some table?

Comment: Snare- Good question, it's a cron that runs it daily.

Manwal - Cron, and sendmail.

3. That's seems like a solid approach.

4. This is what i was thinking originally, or to just increment the value every 86400 seconds. 

Thanks for your help so far guys, I'll follow up as soon as I get one of these methods working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use difference between days to get id , so every day you got a new id

```
class Helper
{

    public static $start=1523664000; //2018-04-13



    public static function getRowOfToday(){

        $now = time(); // or your date as well
        $datediff = $now - Helper::$start;
        $id = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

        return $id;
    }

}
```

then you can call `Helper::getRowOfToday()` to get the current row